# value in render is not taking its form on an Ajax refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have the below code

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="selectGroupForManagingCtns" 
action="#{ctnGrpMgmtController.loadCTNsForAGroup}" 
render="ctnListPanel,ctnTable"> 
<a4j:param name="name" assignTo="#{ctnGrpMgmtController.groupId}" /> </a4j:jsFunction> 
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

After loadCTNsForAGroup is executed in the backing bean, the required components are not rendered after an ajax refresh. Have to make an F5 to view them.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `reRender` attribute instead of `render`

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/jsFunction.html

Comment: hie.. thanks for the reply. reRender attribute is deprecated in richfaces4 but. I found that it is a JSTL function that is actually scrwed my page.  the panel which am trying to render has this JSTL function . rendered="#{fn:length(ctnGrpMgmtController.ctnDetailsList) gt 0}". though the CTN List size is 0, the ajax is failing to render the panel.

Comment: An alternative I am planning is to render the the component and hide/ show it conditionally, instead of using JSTL to decide.